# How I can solve this problem in Visual Studio when i use whisper and pytube?

Tags: python

I tried to transcribe the audio of a youtube video with the IA of whisper with the next code:

```
import pytube
import whisper

youtubeUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a419iZMeN0o&ab_channel=SinEmbargoAlAire"
youtubeVideo = pytube.YouTube(youtubeUrl)

audio = youtubeVideo.streams.get_audio_only()
audio.download(filename='tmp.mp4')

model = whisper.load_model("small")
result = model.transcribe('tmp.mp4')

print(result['text'])
```

When I run the code I receive the next message in the terminal:

> PS C:\Users\fenix.vscode> &C:/Users/fenix/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe
> "c:/Users/fenix/.vscode/import pytube.py"
> Traceback (most recent calllast):
> File "c:\Users\fenix.vscode\import pytube.py", line 2, in
>
> import whisper   File "C:\Users\fenix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\whisper.py",
> line 69, in 
> libc = ctypes.CDLL(libc_name)   File "C:\Users\fenix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ctypes_*init*_.py",
> line 364, in **init**
> if '/' in name or '\' in name: TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I already install whisper, pytube, in the Git the example says I need ffmpeg, I also installed it

I dont't undestand whats the problem.

Comment: Looks similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74250001/12511801) - probably some bug with whisper, so, you can post the issue on their [GitHub](https://github.com/graphite-project/whisper/issues) as well.

Comment: Hey, I'm getting the same error, did you manage to fix it @jesus ?